# Laravel 5.4 - Exibir todos telefones de cada resultado

Tags: laravel, select

Tenho a tabela `convenios` e `telefones`, cada `convenio` possui 1 ou vários `telefones` e uma tela onde são listados todos `convenios`, preciso que venha junto todos os telefones relacionados a cada convenio.

Não posso fazer a busca na tabela telefones na mesma `SQL` que trago os resultados dos `convenios`, pois como pode ter mais de um `telefone`, vai multiplicar os resultados.

Como que ficaria esse `select`?

***Model Telefone***

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Telefone extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'telefones';
    protected $fillable = ['fone', 'id_medico'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function convenio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Convenio::class, 'id_convenio', 'id');
    }
}
```

***Model Convenio***

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Convenio extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'convenios';
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'descricao', 'id_cidade'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function telefones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Telefone::class, 'id_convenio', 'id');
    }

    public function endereco()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Endereco::class, 'id_convenio','id');
    }

    public function convServ()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ConvServ::class, 'id_convenio','id');
    }

    //Filtros de busca

    public function scopeCidade($convenios, $filtro)
    {
        if($filtro != 'all' && $filtro != '')
            return $convenios->where('id_cidade', $filtro);
    }

    public function scopeServico($convenios, $filtro)
    {
        if($filtro != 'all' && $filtro != '')
            return $convenios->where('id_servico', $filtro);
    }

    public function scopeEspecialidade($convenios, $filtro)
    {
        if($filtro != 'all' && $filtro != '')
            return $convenios->where('id_especialidade', $filtro);
    }

    public function scopeBuscar($convenios, $filtro)
    {
        if($filtro != '')
            return $convenios->where('nome', 'LIKE', '%' . $filtro . '%');
    }
}
```

***Controller***

```
public function busca(Request $request)
{
    $title = 'Busca';

    $cidades = Cidade::pluck('nomeCidade', 'id')->all();

    $servicos = Servico::pluck('nomeServ', 'id')->all();

    $convenios = Convenio::cidade($request->get('cidade'))
                        ->servico($request->get('servico'))
                        ->buscar($request->get('buscar'))
                        ->especialidade($request->get('especialidade'))
                        ->join("conv_servs", "convenios.id", "conv_servs.id_convenio")
                        ->join("especialidades", "especialidades.id", "conv_servs.id_especialidade")
                        ->join('cidades', 'cidades.id', 'convenios.id_cidade')
                        ->join('enderecos', 'enderecos.id_convenio', 'convenios.id')
                        ->select('cidades.nomeCidade', 'convenios.id', 'convenios.nome', 'especialidades.nomeEsp', 'enderecos.*')
                        ->orderby('nome', 'asc')
                        ->paginate(5);

    return view('site.busca', compact('title', 'convenios', 'cidades', 'servicos', 'fones'));
}
```

***PS:*** Aquelas funções que aparecem na `query`(*cidade, especialidade, servico e buscar*) são filtros que fiz para a busca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o método [with](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) da seguinte forma:

```
public function busca(Request $request)
{
    $title = 'Busca';

    $cidades = Cidade::pluck('nomeCidade', 'id')->all();

    $servicos = Servico::pluck('nomeServ', 'id')->all();

    $convenios = Convenio::with('telefones')
                        ->cidade($request->get('cidade'))
                        ->servico($request->get('servico'))
                        ->buscar($request->get('buscar'))
                        ->especialidade($request->get('especialidade'))
                        ->join("conv_servs", "convenios.id", "conv_servs.id_convenio")
                        ->join("especialidades", "especialidades.id", "conv_servs.id_especialidade")
                        ->join('cidades', 'cidades.id', 'convenios.id_cidade')
                        ->join('enderecos', 'enderecos.id_convenio', 'convenios.id')
                        ->select('cidades.nomeCidade', 'convenios.id', 'convenios.nome', 'especialidades.nomeEsp', 'enderecos.*')
                        ->orderby('nome', 'asc')
                        ->paginate(5);

    return view('site.busca', compact('title', 
                'convenios', 
                'cidades', 
                'servicos', 
                'fones')
            );
}
```

onde cada `convenio` encontrado é feito o carregamento em uma lista dos `telefones` correspondente do `convenio`.

---

Para exibir os dados:

```
foreach($convenios as $convenio)
{
    $convenio-> ... campos
    foreach($convenio->telefones as $telefone)
    {
        $telefone-> ... campos
    }
}
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)
- [Eloquent: Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)
- [Laravel - Eloquent “Has”, “With”, “WhereHas” - What do they mean? - SO<sup>en</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean)

Comment: Utilizei o método with, então na hora de exibir lá na view, não seria só fazer isso?             @foreach($convenios as $convenio)
                    {{$convenio->fone}}
            @endforeach

Comment: Não dá erro nenhum, mas não exibe nada.

Comment: @DiegoVieira existe uma comando chamado `var_dump` que mostra o retorno e seria legal você verificar o que foi carregado. O `with('telefones')` no seu caso traz uma coleção de telefones então seria um outro `foreach` só para os telefones algo como eu fiz na edição:

Comment: Era isso mesmo, funcionando perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!